# Redirect button in php

Tags: php, html

Hello guys I want to redirect a user to another page when clicking on a button on my webpage, but I dont know how to do it. My buttons are "home", "coffee", "shop" and "about us". When clicking on any of these, I want to get to another page. Can anyone help please?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/stylesheet.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="banner">             
            </div>

            <nav id="navigation">
                <ul id="nav">
                    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Coffee</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

            <div id="content_area">
                <?php echo $content; ?>
            </div>

            <div id="sidebar">

            </div>

            <footer>
                <p>All rights reserved</p>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and this is my index code:

```
   <?php
  $title = "Coffee Webpage";
 $content = '<img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?     q=tbn:ANd9GcSmRPsVdzF4BYRWbF3yBpbkW-1ZjyURYWX1JQm0e6RAbJPR0H76" class="imgLeft" />
 <h3>Title 1</h3>
 <p>

 </p>

<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTdJv4yTpue170rTnOn9unKMgYWeOSPxBP9LoBwvUvhcDJNFcPG6w" class="imgRight"/> 
 <h3>Title 2</h3>
<p>

</p> 

<img src="http://seattle.eat24hours.com/files/cuisines/v4/coffee.jpg?e24v=225" class="imgLeft" />
<h3>Title 3</h3>
<p>




</p>';

include 'Template.php';
?>
```

Comment: @Michael Seeing [OP's comment...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30268835/redirect-button-in-php#comment48637896_30269054), is HTML 101. Could it be *that simple?* - lol

Comment: @Fred-ii-: He said _button_, so I tried to give the benefit of the doubt... VTC?

Comment: @Michael I doubt the OP knows what they're asking for. I've seen this type of question before, where they have a misconception of what a button is, yet alone an `href` hyperlink. I've closed the question with the link you'll see at the top of their question. Lordie, if someone doesn't know how to create a simple hyperlink, well... I've no idea what their next question will be. Sorry to say, if they don't know that basic syntax, they're in the wrong field.

Answer (score 0):

add the url to that page in to your link so for example if the page coffes is `coffe.php` then put `coffe.php` in there.

alternately put your full url which I would recommend.

you could also add this before your link to get the site url using php

```
<?php echo "http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you'd want to do this by adding a front controller; or, in your case, turning your index.php into a front controller.

```
<?php
$page = $_GET['page'];
switch($page) {
    case 'coffee':
        // set variables
        break;
    case 'another':
        // set variables to something else
        break;
}

require 'template.php';
```

Comment: Sorry, and your links would point to index.php?page=coffee

Comment: when I clicked on any of the buttons it showed me the homepage, but now I put the other pages as links for the buttons and it does redirect me to another blank page.

Answer (score 0):

Put a link to each page in their corrosponding a href attributes.

Example:

```
<li><a href="link to coffee page.ext">Coffee</a></li>
<li><a href="link to shop page.ext">Shop</a></li>
<li><a href="link to about page.ext">About us</a></li>
```

Comment: thank you I tried it and it works